# Summing values of a pandas data frame given a list of columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
1  2  3  4  5  6
3  4  5  6  3  3
1  2  3  6  1  2
```

How could i create a new columns of 'sum' that just adds x1 + x3 + x4

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
1  2  3  4  5  6
3  4  5  6  3  3
1  2  3  6  1  2
```

In my actual dataframe i have about 100 columns, so is there a way to do this without having to manually write x1 + x3 + ... + xn

e.g. given a list [x1, x3, x4.. xn]
     df['sum'] = sum(df[list])
?
Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can check [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use subset of `df` and [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
print df
   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
0   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   3   4   5   6   3   3
2   1   2   3   6   1   2

print df[['x1', 'x3', 'x4']]
   x1  x3  x4
0   1   3   4
1   3   5   6
2   1   3   6

li =  ['x1', 'x3', 'x4']
print df[li]
   x1  x3  x4
0   1   3   4
1   3   5   6
2   1   3   6

print df[li].sum()
x1     5
x3    11
x4    16
dtype: int64

print df[li].sum(axis=1)
0     8
1    14
2    10
dtype: int64
```